# TableLayout items on the left and right

Tags: android, android-layout

hy!

I want to have a `TextView` on the left and the right. But both is on the right. all settings should be done by code.

Another quest:

How to add´a horizantal line? by making a nother `TableRow`?

Photo:

[image]
My code:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tl);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Test");
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv2.setText("Test");
        tr.addView(tv);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this stuff,

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tl);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv2.setText("Test");
    tr.addView(tv);
    tr.addView(tv2);
    tl.addView(tr);
    setContentView(tl);
```